Why does my program not find my DLL file?
I have a program and it worked just fine, but when I compiled my MainDLL.dll file, my program won't find it. It returns (0x7E) (The specified module could not be found). The .dll file is in the same folder as the .exe file. But when I tried to open a different .dll file from the same folder, it works just fine.
The main entry program code looks like this:
#include "WinMain.hpp"

    int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInst, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInst, 
        _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd) {
        dbg::SetDebugState(true);
    
        mf::InitMF(L"MainDLL.dll");
    
        int iResult = mf::MainFunc(hInst, hPrevInst, lpCmdLine, nShowCmd);
    
        mf::UninitMF();
    
        return iResult;
    } 

It runs my .lib library that should load the MainDLL.dll file via mf::InitMF(L"MainDLL.dll"); function call.
The .lib library code looks like this:
#include "../Libs/MainLib.hpp"

mf::MainFuncPtr mf::MainFunc = nullptr;

namespace __mf {
    HMODULE hmLib = nullptr;
}

void mf::InitMF(LPCWSTR Path) {

    HRESULT hr = 0l;

    __mf::hmLib = LoadLibraryW(Path);
    if (__mf::hmLib == nullptr) {
        hr = (HRESULT)GetLastError();
        dbg::ErrorWnd(L"load main dll func error", L"Chyba", hr, __LINE__, __FILEW__);
        ExitProcess(13u);
    }

    mf::MainFunc = (mf::MainFuncPtr)GetProcAddress(
        __mf::hmLib, "__MainFunc");
    if (mf::MainFunc == nullptr) {
        hr = (HRESULT)GetLastError();
        dbg::ErrorWnd(L"get main proc error", L"Chyba", hr, __LINE__, __FILEW__);
        ExitProcess(13u);
    }
}

void mf::UninitMF(void) {
    FreeLibrary(__mf::hmLib);
} 

Since any other .dll file loads just fine, I think it's something with the MainDLL.dll file, but when I compile it, it compiles without any problem.
Last thing I did in MainDLL.dll was that I included my other DLL for drawing using D2D1, and after that I cannot load it.
I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2022.

Enable loader snaps to find out which module cannot be found and where the system is looking for it.

DLL can fail to load for amny reasons, one of them is that they cannot be found. Another is that a DLL that they depend on cannot be found. Try using a dependency walker to see if you DLL depends on any other DLLs (that cannot be found).

Dependency Walker is wildly useless these days. It does not know one bit about API sets introduced in Windows 7.

This program is supposed to fix that: https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Another option is SysInternals Process Monitor, which can show you filesystem activity, and will tell you which files your exe is searching for, where it is looking for them, and whether they were found or not.


Since any other .dll file loads just fine, I think it's something with the MainDLL.dll file... Last thing I did in MainDLL.dll was that I included my other DLL for drawing using D2D1, and after that I cannot load it.

This is likely the root of your problem. It is not that MainDLL.dll itself can't be found, as you claim, but rather that another DLL that MainDLL.dll depends on can't be found. Make sure all relevant DLLs are in your EXE's folder (or at least on the system search path).

This is pretty thin on details. It's effectively a guess without ever attempting to determine the root cause. This is largely unhelpful.

I found out that in my header file MainLib.hpp I had wrong path to my MainDLL.hpp header. after changing the path the program runs ok
#pragma once
#include "../Libs/MainDLL.hpp"
//#include "MainDLL.hpp" - fails to load MainDLL.dll library

namespace mf {
    extern mf::MainFuncPtr MainFunc;

    void InitMF(LPCWSTR Path);

    void UninitMF(void);
}

Edit 1:
I forgot that I also deleted all everything associated with my GUI_DLL.dll lib
Edit 2:
In my MainDLL.dll file I included GUI_DLL.lib that was created with my GUI_DLL.dll library. When I got rid of the GUI_DLL.lib the program still won't load the MainDLL.dll and after changing the path to the MainDll.hpp header the program started working

That's incredibly unlikely to have been the root cause.

This is very odd. The location of a header file should have nothing to do with not loading a dll that was successfully compiled unless you have multiple headers of the same name and the compilation used the other header and somehow this changed what functions go in the dll or what functions were exported from the dll.

.lib files are link-time assets. Deleting them has no run-time impact. Without understanding the problem, there is no chance to come up with a solution. If you cannot explain why your proposed solution solved the issue, that solution ain't.
